# refresh timespan using jquery

Tags: jquery, refresh

I have a page in php which displays timespan like,

> created  10 Minutes 23 Seconds ago

I want to update it automatically , without page reloads, so that the seconds , minutes changes dynamically. I can put that in a separate div if needed..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You con use [jquery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin. Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/U5PKb/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Every 10 seconds its called.

```
function getTime(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'time.php',
      success: function(data) {
      $('#timeElement').html(data);
       setTimeout(function(){getTime();}, 10000);
     }
   });
}

getTime();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but I am not using any external script for setting the  time in pages, but its directly pulled from a database.is there any way to auto refresh a div ?

Comment: One thing you could do is convert the function that does that in php (the one that calculates days/hours/mins) to javascript and update an element with its results every few minutes. But if you want it to pull from the database each time it refreshes, you would have to make an ajax request.